# Azure Workbooks barchart does not split data by 3rd column values as does azure analytics log query

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitor-workbooks

in my workbook i added a query from application insights, that, in Application Insights, i render as column chart like this:
[image]

In my workbook it is rendered like this though:
[image]

Why is the workbook not splitting the values of my chart according to the 3rd column values as my application insights does?
Here is the script:

```
let latestVersionAndroid = toscalar(customEvents
| where client_OS contains "Android"
| summarize max(application_Version));
let releaseDateLatestAndroid = toscalar(customEvents
| where client_OS contains "Android" and application_Version contains latestVersionAndroid
| summarize min(timestamp));
customEvents
| where timestamp > releaseDateLatestAndroid
    and name == 'Login'
| project client_OS, OS_Name = customDimensions.OsName, Os_Version = customDimensions.OsVersion, application_Version
| summarize amount = count()
    by tostring(Os_Version), tostring(OS_Name)
| top 10 by amount desc nulls last
| render columnchart
```

it is exactly the same in both my workbook and my log analytics query.
Also in my workbook the following settings are set:
time range: set in query
Visualization: set by query

i already tried the series setting to group by os_name in the workbook, but this has no effect.

Does someone have an answer for me how to do this? because as it is in the workbook now, the graphic is not very good readable and thus pointless.

Many thanks in advance,
Maverick

Answer (score 1):

the bar charts in Azure Workbooks do not yet support 2 levels of grouping.

The charts in the logs UI are based on different technology (their own), while workbooks is built on top of the azure portal framework and behave a little differently.  We're working on consolidating this as time goes on, but at the current time, the workbooks based bar charts are limited to just one dimension for generating "series" grouping.

Comment: Will be 2 levels of grouping feature included in "consolidating"? If yes do you have some time schedule of release? Thanks

Comment: the consolidation part is a long term process (months/semesters), but a specific story for this change, to support multiple levels of segmentation / grouping is *planned* for this semester, but not committed to yet.

Comment: Any update on this? Is it still not possible to summarize by two properties in Azure Workbooks?

Comment: unfortunately, nothing production ready

Answer (score 1):

Bar chart in workbooks has no problem to show stacked bar chart when you have one string column and multiple integer ones.

I solved this issue with [pivot function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin).

try use something like this:

```
customEvents
| project client_OS, OS_Name = customDimensions.OsName, Os_Version = customDimensions.OsVersion, application_Version
| summarize amount = count()
    by tostring(Os_Version), tostring(OS_Name)
| top 10 by amount desc nulls last
| evaluate pivot(Os_Version, sum(amount))
| render columnchart
```

which should give you desired result:

```
version | androidSum | iosSum
v1      | 1          | 2
v2      | 0          | 12
```